# Proper way to ask someone what they think about the reason of something

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Let's say Person A is crying. I want to ask Person B that why Person A is crying.

1. *Why do you think **he is** crying?*
2. *Why do you think **is he** crying?*

Which one is the correct way of asking this question?

If I ask it the first way could Person B can say "I don't think he is crying". Note the question.

Comment: This question should be asked on our sister site dedicated to people learning English as a foreign language: [ELL.se]. The short answer is option 2 is completely unidiomatic: no native speaker would ever phrase it that way. Your qualms about how Person B might (irrelevantly) respond are unfounded: you asked *why*, not *whether*. The interrogative *why* demands a *reason* as a response.

Comment: "No, I don't think he is crying" would be the answer to "Do you think he is crying?" If you remove the "No", however, it could be a possible answer to the question about knowing why he's crying.

Comment: @MorganFR I edited the "No" part. I inform you because otherwise your comment would have looked meaningless.

Comment: @DanBron Even though there is "Why" in the sentence, the answer is still valid. You are asking Why PersonB thinks that Person A is crying. And he can say "I think he is crying because I see moist in his eyes". Could I made it clear?

Comment: @ozgur Yes, but pragmatics (e.g. Grisham's maxims) preclude such a response, except for someone who was *deliberately* being obtuse (usually as a silly joke). In other words: option 1 *is* how native speakers actually ask this question. But anyway, whatever the merits or demerits of option 1, the question is moot, because option 2 is impossible (anyone hearing you use it would consider it a solecism or gaffe, and such use would likely mark you as a non-native speaker).

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the ambiguous "why" of motivation: my old enemy, we meet again!

My job often requires of me that I ask people what their hypotheses are for third parties' behaviors.  I have to be very, very, very careful how I phrase such questions, because, as you have noticed, the question "Why do you think he is crying?" can be parsed two very different ways:

> "What do you think his reason is for crying?"

vs.

> "What are your reasons for thinking he is crying?"

The second of these two questions – *especially* when phrased using the word "why", which is idiomatically used in rhetorical questions to express *anger* – can be construed as an *insult*.  If you ask "why do you think he is crying?" in the right (or rather *wrong*) tone of voice and context, it will be construed as your having said, "What's kind of idiot are you that you mistakenly think that he is crying?"

As someone who has to ask both the "what are your reasons for thinking this" and the "what do you think his reasons are" questions on a regular basis, and make sure that I keep them distinct and don't antagonize anyone I ask them of, I'll tell you: there is no simple easy *grammatical* way to do so.

The way I do it is by explaining myself in detail using lots of words, and/or by pursuing the question by entirely other words:

> How did you know he was crying?
>
> What did you see that let you know he was crying?
>
> Did you see him crying?

vs.

> What reason did he have for crying?
>
> Did he say why he was crying?
>
> I wonder why he was crying.

Comment: "Why do you think he is crying?" can be unambiguous in a context where the fact of his crying has already been established.